# How to get class methods?

Tags: ruby

Ruby `Module` has a method `instance_methods` that can return a list of methods of that class. But how to retrieve class methods list of a class?

Comment: You want *class methods* that are **only** defined in that particular class **not** that are inherited(/included), right?

Answer (score 8):

You can pass the `false` parameter to [Object#methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-methods).

```
class Foo
  def self.bar
  end
end

Foo.methods(false) #=> [:bar]
```

Comment: Add **s** to Object#method and its link.

Answer (score 2):

Go to rails console with the command:

```
rails c
```

type:

```
 Class.methods
```

and you will get them all in a list.

If you want to get a specific class' method, then type:

```
Class_name.methods
```

Comment: I think you meant `Class_name.method` for your last example.  No `s` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to know is that there is no such thing as a class method in Ruby. What we colloquially call a "class method" is actually nothing more than a normal singleton method. *All* objects can have singleton methods, there's nothing special about classes.

Actually, there is no thing as a singleton method, either! What we colloquially call a "singleton method" is really just a regular boring instance method of the object's singleton class.

So, since you already know how to list instance methods, and you now know that class methods are actually instance methods, you already know how to answer your own question:

```
class Foo; def self.bar; end end

class << Foo
  instance_methods(false)
end
# => [:bar]

Foo.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
# => [:bar]
```

However, even if singleton methods don't actually exist, it is still useful to talk about them, and the above constructs are *just* inconvenient enough that there are actually specialized methods which perform the equivalent of the above:

```
Foo.singleton_methods(false)
# => [:bar]
```

Comment: When using singleton_methods, it seems argument false isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Song
  def self.hello;end
end
p Song.singleton_methods
```

result：

```
[:hello]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have this:

```
object = Object.new
```

and you want to get list of class methods of `Object`(parent of `object`) you can get via:

```
object.class.methods
```

And if you have some class, let say `Samuel` you can get *class methods* easily via `Samuel.methods`. You can do this because `Samuel` is **instance of class Class** hence you can get its methods like from normal objects.